# Django Class based view and generic view details usage

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I'm wirting a django app for inventory management. I would like django to process a url like the one below

"foo:8000/stores/Electrical Store/" where "Electrical Store" is generated by a view - another - that displays a list of stores. The http response was generated using a ListView  generic view - and can also be generated using a Template view, I tried different  alternatives while trying to familiarize myself with how class based views work.

My problem is when trying to get django to render an http page with "store details" and the list of products in the store I get a 404 error below:

^stores/(?P\w+)/$ [name='stores_product']
The current URL, Electrical Store/, didn't match any of these.

and I'm not really sure where I've gone wrong in my code - basically the docs don't provide enough information or examples to demonstrate the concepts they are trying to convey. I've provided the relevant models and views below. Please help...

```
# models
    # PRODUCT MODEL
    class Product(models.Model):
       # Desription - ID
       name = models.CharField(primary_key = True, unique = True, max_length = 100)
       description = models.TextField(max_length = 200)

       # Amount per containment unit
       amount_per_containment_unit = models.IntegerField("Unit Count", default = 0)

       def __unicode__(self):
          # return unicode(self.datetime)
          return unicode(self.name)

       class Meta:
          ordering = ["name"]


    # STORE MODEL
    # A Store has a name, an address, a phone number, a group of users who act as curators and a list of stock
    # items.
    class Store(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 100)
       address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
       phone = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
       curators = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name = "Curator", blank = True, null = True)
       products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through = "StoreProduct", blank = True, null = True)

       # Curator list
       def curator_list(self):
          return ",\n".join([obj.first_name for obj in self.curators.all()])

       def __unicode__(self):
          # return unicode(self.datetime)
          return unicode(self.name)

       class Meta:
          ordering = ["name"]


    # StoreProduct MODEL
    class StoreProduct(models.Model):
       store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
       product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
       quantity =  models.IntegerField(default = 0)
       total = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

       class Meta:
          unique_together = (("store", "product"),)

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(StoreProduct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          if self.total == None and self.store and self.product and not self.pk:
             self.total = self.product.amount_per_containment_unit * self.quantity

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          if self.store and self.product and self.quantity:
             self.total = self.product.amount_per_containment_unit * self.quantity

          super(StoreProduct, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
# views

    class StoreList(TemplateView):
       # Template
       template_name = "inventory/store/store_list.html"

       # Context
       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          context = super(StoreList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
          context["store_list"] = Store.objects.all()

          return context


    class StoreProductList(TemplateView):
       template_name = "inventory/store/store_products.html"

       # Context
       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          # Objects
          self.store_inst = Store.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs["name"])
          self.queryset = StoreProduct.objects.filter(store = self.store_inst)

          print self.store_inst

          context = super(StoreList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

          # Store primary key
          context["store"] = self.store_inst
          context["store_products"] = self.queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

The 404 might be because you have a space character in the URL that's being encoded to %20, that then doesn't match the `\w` part of the regular expression.